# How to determine the depth of file path?

Tags: python, path

I have a path as a string like this:

```
path = "directory/folder1/folder2/folder3/file1.txt"
```

I want to know how many levels this path has - in this case 4 (`directory`, `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`).

What's the best way to do it in Python? I thought about counting the "/":

```
path.count("/")
```

but I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: `path.count('/')` is probably the easiest way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it quite easily using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("directory/folder1/fodler2/folder3/file1.txt")

print(len(path.parents), list(path.parents))
```

Which gives:

```
5 [Path('directory/folder1/fodler2/folder3'), Path('directory/folder1/fodler2'), Path('directory/folder1'), Path('directory'), Path('.')]
```

As can be seen, the results is 5 because `"."` is also in the list as `"directory/folder1/fodler2/folder3/file1.txt"` is implicitly equal to `"./directory/folder1/fodler2/folder3/file1.txt"` so you can always just subtract 1 from the result.

---

Compared to `path.count('/')`, this is platform-independent...

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how precise you want to be. Problems I can think of:

- Are you sure the last part of the string is the filename? If it is a directory, does it matter?
- Are you sure the path separator is '/'? os.sep is your separator.
- What if the string starts with os.sep?
- What if some os.sep is repeated? For example os.path.exists("/var//log") returns True.

This might be slightly better, but the solution with pathlib.Path is definitely better.

```
os.path.normpath(path).count(os.sep)
```

Comment: I want to keep only paths ending with filenames

Comment: Your fourth point is a valid point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one optimal solution could be `path.count(os.sep)`. However, Tomerikoo answer is better than this. However, Make sure that `pathlib` module is installed, as this module does not come by default in the standard distribution of python2. But if you are using python3. Then it comes by default.